# Maya Python: cannot import name 'cmds' from 'maya.cmds'

Tags: python, maya

I know this problem probably seems dumb and simple: but let me give you some context. Antcgi released a ribbon builder script you can buy here: https://ko-fi.com/s/73d8faa0e8

Now I tried to get his script to run: I put "import antcgiRibbon
antcgiRibbon.antcgiRibbonUI()" in a blank python tab and tried running it after pasting it to my scripts folder (I am running maya 2022.3)

Only one problem: I keep getting the error

```
"# Error: ImportError: file d:/Users/Username/Documents/maya/2022/scripts\antcgiRibbon.py line 1: cannot import name 'cmds' from 'maya.cmds' (C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\Python37\lib\site-packages\maya\cmds__init__.py) #"
```

Now I cant post his script here, as that would be morally unethical: but as somebody who does python coding I was able to dissect his script and I noticed there was a different way he imports commands

When I import maya commands I usually start with

```
import re
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel
import pymel.core as pm
from functools import partial
```

His maya import commands start with

```
from maya.cmds import cmds
from pymel.core import core as pm
from maya.mel import mel
from functools import partial
```

Now if I replace his command import with mine, I can get the UI to load: but none of the buttons work. When I try it with his command import line, the script straight up refuses to work and I get the error

`"# Error: ImportError: file d:/Users/Username/Documents/maya/2022/scripts\antcgiRibbon.py line 1: cannot import name 'cmds' from 'maya.cmds' (C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\Python37\lib\site-packages\maya\cmds__init__.py) #"`

From what I've researched there seems to be minimum to no difference between "import maya.cmds as cmds" and "from maya.cmds import cmds" unless someone can explain why one partially works and the other just doesnt. Does it have to do with installed versions of python? Is my version to old or too new? What would cause that maya error?

It's not just this script either, if I try to run any script I type out with "from maya.cmds import cmds" refuses to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there seems to be minimum to no difference between "import maya.cmds as cmds" and "from maya.cmds import cmds"

There is a *huge* difference.

The first one is importing `maya.cmds`.

The second one is importing `maya.cmds.cmds`.

"import x from y" expects x to be a variable inside of y or a sub-module underneath y.

Comment: Thank you @JohnGordon, that does clarify my question partially, but if I wanted to get "from maya.cmds import cmds" working, what would I have to add to get it to work properly?

Comment: or even better @JohnGordon, how would I rewrite "from functools import partial" to match with my command structure: because maybe the reason I cant get the buttons to work is because all the other commands are importing except for functools because it starts with "from"

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with `from functools import partial`.

Comment: I don't understand why antcgi's code would say `from maya.cmds import cmds`...